# Kendo grid showing white blank area at the bottom of the grid

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I have implemented a kendo mvc grid and having only 3 records. It is showing blank white space at the bottom of the grid. I would like to show rows only for the records. How do  I eliminate the white space

[image]

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.ActivityViewModel>()
        .Name("GridActivity")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.ActivityID).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(o => o.ServiceID);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ActivityAppliesToName);
            columns.Bound(o => o.TeamName);
            columns.Bound(o => o.FullName);
            columns.Bound(o => o.EmployeeID);
            columns.Bound(o => o.RequiredBy);
            columns.Bound(o => o.CompletedDate);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Status);
            columns.Bound(o => o.CountryCode);
            columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedDate);
            columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedBy);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ModifiedDate);
        })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add Activity"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
    .TemplateName("ActivityEdit")
    .Window(w=>w.Width(600)))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ActivityID))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Activity_Create", "Activity"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Activity_Read", "Activity", new { id = 5 }))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Activity_Update", "Activity"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("Activity_Delete", "Activity"))
    )
    )
```

Comment: Check if the div element where the grid was created doesn't haves a *height* set. Check [this example](http://dojo.telerik.com/iZiXa).

Comment: I have checked . There is no height specified for the div element

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is related to the paging options - if you turn off paging, it will shrink to fit the number of records displayed.

Additionally, you may find this Telerik forum thread useful: [Dynamic Grid Height?](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamic-grid-height)